# Trying to combine elements in an array with for loop

Tags: java, arrays

I am having trouble with the logic for this loop.

```
a[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
b[3] = {6, 7, 8}
c[3] = {9, 10, 11}
d[3] = {12, 13, 14}
```

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
1, 6, 9, 12
1, 6, 9, 13
1, 6, 9, 14
1, 6, 10, 12
1, 6, 10, 13
```

..etc

I have 4 for loops all within the other, but that doesn't seem to work. Can anyone help me out?

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

            System.out.print(a[i]);

            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {

                System.out.print(b[j]);

                for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {

                    System.out.print(c[k]);

                    for (int m = 0; m < 3; m++) {

                        System.out.print(d[m]);
                        System.out.println();

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What isn't working? Do you get an error? Not the desired output? (If yes, then please [edit] your question to include the error message/current output)

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {

            for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {

                for (int m = 0; m < 3; m++) {
                    System.out.print(a[i]);
                    System.out.print(b[j]);
                    System.out.print(c[k]);
                    System.out.print(d[m]);
                    System.out.println();

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Just a little logical issue. You want to show the a, b and c array values during each iteration, so this will do it.
I do not really code in Java so my synthax could be wrong, but the logic is on point, I believe.

Comment: Might be better to replace the conditions with `i < a.length` for example

Comment: Even better using backtracking, if the number of arrays is unknown before runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int [] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int [] b = {6, 7, 8};
    int [] c = {9, 10, 11};
    int [] d = {12, 13, 14};
    for(int i =0; i < a.length; i++) {
      for(int j =0; j < b.length; j++){
        for(int l =0; l < c.length; l++) {
          for(int m =0; m < d.length; m++) {
            System.out.printf("%d, %d, %d, %d\n",a[i],b[j],c[l],d[m]);
        }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

You can try in [Ideone](https://ideone.com/FaFFs0)